# djagno filter regex not working while python re works

Tags: mysql, regex, django, django-models, django-mysql

I am trying to do iregex match in django for the **regular expression**

```
reg_string = (\w|\d|\b|\s)+h(\w|\d|\b|\s)+(\w|\d|\b|\s)+anto(\w|\d|\b|\s)+
self.queryset.filter(name__iregex=r"%s"%(reg_string,))
```

by using the word **"The Canton" for name** but its not returning any value but while using it in **python re.search** its working

```
print (re.search(r'(\w|\d|\b|\s)+h(\w|\d|\b|\s)+(\w|\d|\b|\s)+anto(\w|\d|\b|\s)+', 'The Canton', re.I).group()
```

I am using Mysql 5.7, any one know how to fix this

Comment: Do you mean the pattern must conform to the MySQL REGEXP syntax? Try `[_[:alnum:][:space:]]+h[_[:alnum:][:space:]]+anto[_[:alnum:][:space:]]+` then

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - It worked

Comment: Please remove the django-mysql tag, which is meant for the library django-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that MySQL `REGEXP` does not support shorthand character classes like `\s`, `\d`, `\w`, etc. It supports some basic POSIX character classes like `[:digit:]`, `[:alpha:]`, `[:alnum:]`, etc.

Even if you keep on using the pattern in Python, you should not write `(\w|\d|\b|\s)+` as it matches and captures a single char that is a word char or digit, word boundary, or whitespace, 1 or more times (and rewriting buffer of Group N with the latest char the engine matched). You could rewrite that with a single character class - `[\w\s]+`.

Now, your pattern in MySQL will look like

```
[_[:alnum:][:space:]]+h[_[:alnum:][:space:]]+anto[_[:alnum:]‌​[:space:]]+
```

where `[\w\s]+`  is turned into `[_[:alnum:][:space:]]+`:

- `[` - start of a bracket expression
- `_`  - an underscore (as `\w` matches `_` and `[:alnum:]` does not)
- `[:alnum:]`  - an alphanuemric char
- `[:space:]` - any whitespace char
- `]` - end of the bracket expression
- `+` - quantifier, 1 or more times.